# hadoop map reduce program not showing the output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I have wriiten map reduce program in java

```
public class myproject {

   public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {
     private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
     private Text word = new Text();

     public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
       String line = value.toString();
         /*
           MY CODE
         */
         output.collect(new Text(string1),new Text(string2));
       }
     }
public class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
     public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Text> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {

       while (values.hasNext()) {
         /*
            MY CODE
         */
             values.next();
                     }
       output.collect(key, new IntWritable(val));
     }
        }
       public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 JobConf conf = new JobConf(myproject.class);
 conf.setJobName("myprojectwork");

 conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
 conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

     conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
     conf.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

 conf.setMapperClass(Map.class);
 conf.setCombinerClass(Reduce.class);
 conf.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

 conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
 conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

 FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
 FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

 JobClient.runJob(conf);
```

now when i try to run it using

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/showstatus.jar myproject projectfolder/input projectfolder/output
```

it shows only this and then exits

```
WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

when i try to list the projectfolder/output folder
it shows no such file /directory

the wordcount problem working absolutly fine but my program is not working

is there any thing i am missing out

do i have to edit any .xml file in hadoop directory or something like that?

Comment: Are'nt u mixing 2 hadoop api's? In the newer api you are having context object not collector . Change the map method as
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException . Same goes with reducer too

Comment: ok i changed it now its showing this following error
    exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:836)
at myproject.main(myproject.java:68)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

Comment: the exception part, I already have declared shows IOException in both of the map and reduce function

Comment: Could u please edit the code and post what you have run?